# Should we post a catch-all question answering "What's this font?" on TeX.SX?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, duplicates

I was tempted to ask this on the main site, since there has been many such questions I've come across, but thought I'd ask here first. Here are some questions dealing with fonts (some answered successfully, some closed):

- [What is the font in this document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11353/5764)
- [What fonts does this article use?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18624/5764)
- [What font is this?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26774/5764)
- [How do I find out what font is used in this picture/text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28426/5764)
- [Name of the font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40615/5764)
- [Canadian Journal of Mathematics Style & Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43790/5764)
- [What font/style is this?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45683/5764)

This question echoes @doncherry's comment on [How do I find out what font is used in this picture/text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28426/5764):

> Should we have a one-answers-all question "How do I find out what font
>   is used in this picture/text"? (Unless there already is one)

My main question would be whether this is on-topic or not. Answers would describe general ways of obtaining font information, from websites or other means (like `pdffonts`).

---

## This has been asked on the main site: [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/5764)

Comment: …and should this catchall question really be on tex.sx and not elsewhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, I think we really should have such a question. Having a big thread which explains all the ways how to identify the font would be greatly beneficial. Note that while the general question "How to identify the fonts of this document" is clearly on-topic (IMHO), questions like "What's the font(s) of that specific document?" are actually "too localized", because basically no one else will need that information except the OP.

Answer (score 6):

If you do, make sure to mention [the font-identificaton tag on graphicdesign.sx](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-identification).

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add that I consider "What is this font?" questions to be definitely *off topic*.  However, given that we keep getting asked them (with [Font used in mathematical papers in Elsevier journals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45908/86) as the latest and greatest) then a single catch-all that others can be closed as duplicates of is better than a continual drip, drip, drip of these questions.

Comment: Thanks Andrew - this *is* aimed at closing the tap and catching the drips.