# Should we post a general question regarding "why can't I use this macro inside this other macro"?

Tags: discussion

^^ see title.

I think it should be okay? Compare [Should we post a catch-all question answering "What's this font?" on TeX.SX? - TeX - LaTeX Meta Stack Exchange](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2330/should-we-post-a-catch-all-question-answering-whats-this-font-on-tex-sx)

---

#### What's the current problem?

- Answerers keep having to repeat the explanation.
- If they don't, visitors (those who want to learn TeX-programming-language) don't understand what is going on.
- It happens quite frequently (maybe more frequently, this is not easy to search for) – see below.

---

#### Meta

- There are 3 types. (if this is made) should they be split into 3 different questions, or only 1?
- What's the duplicate close vote policy?

  1. Immediately close questions as duplicate of the corresponding one, unless they (later edit to) mention that they already read the linked question and what exactly they don't understand.
  2. Write separate answer that have code to solve OP's specific issue, then link to the corresponding question for the repeated explanation part.
- CW or not? (the font question above isn't CW.)

---

#### Example question.

I have a macro `\innermacro{...}`, when it's used alone it typesets `123` on the document.

Then, I have another macro `\outermacro`, such that `\outermacro{123}` results in `456`.

Now I try to use `\outermacro{\innermacro{...}}`, but it raises mysterious errors.

What is going on?

---

#### Example existing questions

Generally I think there are 3 types:

1. `\innermacro` is catcode-changing.

   Example:

   - [What can and can't occur as macro argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128676/what-can-and-cant-occur-as-macro-argument)
   - [Macro that takes any latex code as an argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489767/macro-that-takes-any-latex-code-as-an-argument)
2. `\innermacro` is not expandable. ("obviously" this category is the most common)

   Example:

   - [Issue with fp "missing number" macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48198/issue-with-fp-missing-number-macro)
   - [\IfSubStr does not work when used as parameter of another macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94250/ifsubstr-does-not-work-when-used-as-parameter-of-another-macro)
   - [My if condition does not work. Any idea why?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452922/my-if-condition-does-not-work-any-idea-why?noredirect=1&lq=1)
   - [\dim_set failed when using \str_if_in in LaTeX3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632499/dim-set-failed-when-using-str-if-in-in-latex3?noredirect=1&lq=1)
   - [How to extract year from date in iso 8601 format?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632603/how-to-extract-year-from-date-in-iso-8601-format?noredirect=1#comment1578029_632603)
   - [What can go wrong when using macros as arguments of other macros?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186041/what-can-go-wrong-when-using-macros-as-arguments-of-other-macros)

   Reference:

   - [What is "expansion"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158827/what-is-expansion?noredirect=1&lq=1)
   - [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands? When and why do we need \protect?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands-when-and-why-do-we-n)
3. `\outermacro` does not expand its arguments.

   Example:

   - [How to create a new command for parameters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/593293/how-to-create-a-new-command-for-parameters)

Comment: Seems like a good idea. Maybe one question with three answers, all CW. Then you can link the appropriate individual answer on a new question.

Comment: It's not that `\IfSubStr` cannot be used in the argument to another macro: it obviously *can* be. Only `\outer` tokens or `\par` cannot appear in the argument to a macro (the latter if the wrapping macro is not `\long`). Even `\verb` can appear in an argument, provided it's the last token in the replacement text.

Comment: Another question today (I think type 3): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633891/package-polyglossia-incomprehensible-warning

Comment: @Marijn (and others) actually I'm somewhat busy now, so someone else can post, otherwise I can do some time later

Comment: Type 3,  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643068/how-to-trim-the-spaces-of-the-head-of-token-list-after-using-tl-tailn  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642819/list-of-macros-as-arguments-to-another-macro (we're having way too many of those I should really write one soon...)

Comment: Type 2, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15100/using-predefined-constants-with-tikz